Can you infer seasonality from these ACF plots?
I want to fit AR and (G)ARCH models to asset returns. Therefore, I have to address the possibility of seasonality, especially in case of commodities. Here are my two ACF plots: The first one relates to a share, the second to daily natural gas spot prices. I find it difficult to conclude that there is a sense of seasonality, but maybe I'm wrong. So I'd like to have a second assessment.
PS: Interestingly, if any, the stock, the asset for which I would not have thought of seasonality - shows periodic behavior.



Could you tell us where you see "periodic behavior," with what period, and how you measure that?

In comp_data are spikes at lag 0, 60, 130 and 220 and valleys between them.

Perhaps, if you squint: but that's not periodic behavior, is it?  At best you can say these locations are approximately whole multiples of 60--but that's not good enough for real periodic behavior.

Yeah, I guess. So, given the data provided you would support my assessment, that there is no seasonality in both cases?

Why not check?  Explore a seasonally differenced model and/or look at the Fourier Transform of the acf.  In my experience this is worth doing when such seasonality is interpretable, such as 91.25 days, 30.5 days, 7 days, 12 hours, and so on, but otherwise the apparent seasonality is more likely to be spurious.

Will do, thank you!
